# images displaying magnifying glass on hover

Tags: html

I am creating a new website locally and for some reason all of my images that I have on my site when you hover over them it displays a + magnifying glass instead of the normal cursor.

The links still work but not sure why the + magnifying glass is appearing. Any help on rectifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not just a browser helper / addin?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this css

```
img {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Or if that doesn't work,

```
img {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

If neither works, you have something strange in your browser over-riding normal operation. If only the second one works, you have something injecting css into your page that you are unaware of.